# npm ERR! invalid: ionic-app-lib@0.5.1-beta.0

Tags: npm, ionic-framework

```
$ ionic info

Your system information:

Cordova CLI: 5.3.3
Ionic CLI Version: 1.7.0
Ionic App Lib Version: 0.5.1-beta.0
ios-deploy version: 1.8.2 
ios-sim version: 5.0.2 
OS: Mac OS X El Capitan
Node Version: v4.1.2
Xcode version: Xcode 7.0.1 Build version 7A1001
```

There is an error:

```
$ npm list -g
/Users/horace/.nvm/versions/node/v4.1.2/lib
├─┬ cordova@5.3.3
│ ├─┬ cordova-lib@5.3.3
.
.
.
  ├─┬ which@1.1.2
  │ └─┬ is-absolute@0.1.7
  │   └── is-relative@0.1.3
  ├── wrappy@1.0.1
  └── write-file-atomic@1.1.3

npm ERR! invalid: ionic-app-lib@0.5.1-beta.0 /Users/horace/.nvm/versions/node/v4.1.2/lib/node_modules/ionic/node_modules/ionic-app-lib
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: update your node version to the latest one and check it once

Comment: I update node to v4.2.1 and npm to 2.14.7, the error is still there.

Comment: I also updated my ionic to 1.7 version and I also faced the same problem ..than again I installed to my older version as `npm install -g ionic@1.4.0` , I will resolve this problem soon and I will update if i found any solution